# How works the method __repr__ of xlwings 's class Apps when it uses repr(list(self))

Tags: python, python-3.x, xlwings

I trying to make a new class and I found a similar class in the module xlwings, but I can't understand how works the method **repr** when it calls to self ("repr(list(self)). How the class knows return a list with the apss ?

The code is:

```
class Apps(object):    
    def __init__(self, impl):
        self.impl = impl

    def __call__(self, i):
        return self[i-1]

    def __repr__(self):
        return '{}({})'.format(
            self.__class__.__name__,
            repr(list(self))
        )

    def __getitem__(self, item):
        return App(impl=self.impl[item])

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.impl)

    def __iter__(self):
        for app in self.impl:
            yield App(impl=app)
```

Answer (score 1):

`list` calls `__iter__` so it's calling `repr` on a list of App objects which will call `App.__repr__` for each item.

Comment: And for what is `__call__` ? Thank you.

Comment: @rvcristiand `__call__` will be called when an instance of Apps is called like a function. The indexing into self will call `__getitem__` which will return App instance of i-1 item.